# Expected to decode Dictionary<String, Any> but found an array instead with Nested Containers

Tags: json, swift, parsing, core-data, codable

So, I am trying to parse this JSON using the Codable protocols:
https://randomuser.me/api/?results=100

That are basically 100 random users.

Here's my User class initializer from decoder, that I need because the User is an entity in a Core Data Model:

```
required convenience public init(from decoder: Decoder) throws {
        let managedObjectContext = CoreDataStack.sharedInstance.persistentContainer.viewContext
        guard let entity = NSEntityDescription.entity(forEntityName: "User", in: managedObjectContext) else {
                fatalError("Failed to decode User")
        }

        self.init(entity: entity, insertInto: managedObjectContext)

        let container = try decoder.container(keyedBy: CodingKeys.self)
        let results = try container.nestedContainer(keyedBy: CodingKeys.self, forKey: .results)
        let name = try results.nestedContainer(keyedBy: CodingKeys.self, forKey: .name)
        firstName = try name.decode(String.self, forKey: .firstName)
        lastName = try name.decode(String.self, forKey: .lastName)

        let location = try results.nestedContainer(keyedBy: CodingKeys.self, forKey: .location)
        let street = try location.decode(String.self, forKey: .street)
        let city = try location.decode(String.self, forKey: .city)
        let postcode = try location.decode(String.self, forKey: .postcode)
        address = street + ", " + city + ", " + postcode

        email = try results.decode(String.self, forKey: .email)

        let pictures = try results.nestedContainer(keyedBy: CodingKeys.self, forKey: .pictures)
        pictureURL = try pictures.decode(String.self, forKey: .pictureURL)
    }
```

This is the defective line:

```
let results = try container.nestedContainer(keyedBy: CodingKeys.self, forKey: .results)
```

Here's the complete error:

```
typeMismatch(Swift.Dictionary<Swift.String, Any>, Swift.DecodingError.Context(codingPath: [], debugDescription: "Expected to decode Dictionary<String, Any> but found an array instead.", underlyingError: nil))
```

I think it's due to the structure of the JSON, that is an array of 100 elements under the key "results", and I think the problem could be in doing them all together.
How should I handle this?

Comment: What is `CodingKeys`?

Comment: You can't handle the whole `result` array in the User init method, it needs to handle one user only. If you don't have it you need a Result struct or class to handle the array.

Comment: Why are so many containers keyed by the same keys?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The error is clear: The value for `results` is an array and `nestedContainers` expects a dictionary.

To decode the user array you need an umbrella struct outside of the Core Data classes.

```
struct Root : Decodable {
   let results: [User]
}
```

While decoding `Root` the `init` method in `User` is called for each array item.

To use `nestedContainers` you have to separate the CodingKeys.

This is the `init` method without the Core Data stuff. `postcode` can be `String` or `Int`

```
private enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey { case name, location, email, picture }
private enum NameCodingKeys: String, CodingKey { case first, last }
private enum LocationCodingKeys: String, CodingKey { case street, city, postcode }
private enum PictureCodingKeys: String, CodingKey { case large, medium, thumbnail }

required convenience public init(from decoder: Decoder) throws {
    let container = try decoder.container(keyedBy: CodingKeys.self)
    let nameContainer = try container.nestedContainer(keyedBy: NameCodingKeys.self, forKey: .name)
    let firstName = try nameContainer.decode(String.self, forKey: .first)
    let lastName = try nameContainer.decode(String.self, forKey: .last)

    let locationContainer = try container.nestedContainer(keyedBy: LocationCodingKeys.self, forKey: .location)
    let street = try locationContainer.decode(String.self, forKey: .street)
    let city = try locationContainer.decode(String.self, forKey: .city)
    let postcode : String
    do {
        let postcodeInt = try locationContainer.decode(Int.self, forKey: .postcode)
        postcode = String(postcodeInt)
    } catch DecodingError.typeMismatch {
        postcode = try locationContainer.decode(String.self, forKey: .postcode)
    }
    let address = street + ", " + city + ", " + postcode

    let email = try container.decode(String.self, forKey: .email)

    let pictureContainer = try container.nestedContainer(keyedBy: PictureCodingKeys.self, forKey: .picture)
    let pictureURL = try pictureContainer.decode(URL.self, forKey: .large)
}
```

Comment: The problem here isn't that all the values are still in the array under the most external key "results" in the json?

Comment: At the moment `init(from` is called **one** item of the `results` array is passed as argument

Comment: So, sorry for the dumb question, but how should I call it? By now it is called like this:

`let decoder = JSONDecoder()
let json = try decoder.decode(User.self, from: data)`

in the closure of the DataTask, what am I missing here?

Comment: No, as mentioned in the answer you have to add the umbrella struct and decode `decoder.decode(Root.self,` the `init` method in `User` is called from `results`

Comment: Ah ok perfect, this worked perfectly! Now, I don't know if what I'm saying it's stupid, but I expected that the initializer would have handled the saving of the new users in the core data database. I opened the database with a tool, but it doesn't seem to do so. Do you have any hint? Thank you very much again!

Comment: You have to save the managed object context after `decoder.decode`.

Comment: It worked perfectelly! I supposed I had to do that, but I don't know why yesterday night I was getting an error. Probably I messed up something while tired. Thank you again very much!

Answer (score 4):

This is a very simplified version but it handles your Json data correctly

```
struct Result : Codable {
    let results: [User]
}
struct User: Codable {
    let gender: String
    let name: Name
}
struct Name: Codable {
    let title: String
    let first: String
    let last: String
}

let decoder = JSONDecoder()
let data = jsonString.data(using: .utf8) //Replace with url download

do {
    let json = try decoder.decode(Result.self, from: data!)
} catch {
    print(error)
}
```

Comment: This is doubtless a great solution to parse this JSON but it's quite unsuitable in a Core Data `NSManagedObject` subclass environment

Comment: @vadian That's true, I intentionally focused my answer on Json issue and ignored the Core Data bit thinking that saving to Core Data can be handled separately.